# OS-X Lion is not auto connecting to my hotspot

Tags: macos, osx-lion, wireless-access-point

My Macbook Pro is not auto connecting to my hotspot. In the past I had 10.6 and the same wireless access point (w/o authentication) and it would auto-connect.

After moving into my new apartment, I installed the wireless access point and setup with WPA2. Now I have to select the hotspot every time I open up the macbook. I have the WAP on the top of the priority list and checked remember networks this computer joined. This is starting to become a pain.

Any idea's on how to make it auto connect every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past I've had to remove the remembered network and let Mac OS X rediscover it before automatic connecting would work.

You can remove a network in System Preferences → Network → Advanced. When you've removed the network, exit from System Preferences then rejoin your network. Hopefully this will let it recognize the network next time it's available.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Cheers!, I wish I could buy you a beer LOL.